# Node GRPC TLS with Reverse proxy (haproxy)

Tags: ssl, haproxy, grpc-node

I'm trying to use a haproxy instance to correctly redirect the requests from the client to the server. But the client can't connect using the haproxy, it only works when I do the request directly to the server.

The unique message error is printed from the client, saying:

> Request not completed. Error: Error: 14 UNAVAILABLE: No connection established

I'm creating the certificates using `openssl`.

I think, there's a problem in the haproxy config file, since works normally when "Client -> Server".

My haproxy config file:

```
global
    daemon

defaults
    mode http
    timeout connect 5s
    timeout client 60s
    timeout server 60s

frontend grpc-front
    bind *:8000 proto h2 ssl crt /usr/local/etc/haproxy/ca.pem

    default_backend grpc-back

backend grpc-back
    server test-server test-server:8000 check fall 3 proto h2 ssl verify required ca-file /usr/local/etc/haproxy/ca.pem
```

Observations:

- The project works normally when connecting directly to the server (Client -> Server);
- The CN defined in the server's certificate is: `test-haproxy`;
- It also works normally when not using TLS;
- All applications (client, haproxy, server) are dockerized and properly connected to each other.

Comment: can you replace proto with alpn and let me know